# Java ArrayList populating

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

So I am creating an method that shuffles a group of numbers and the idea is that i create a population of these numbers.
So I create a loop which shuffles the numbers and then adds it to an arraylist, however after a few debugging statements I found that it does shuffle the numbers but only adds the last shuffle to the arrayList. Can anyone help me figure out why?

solutionList is an arraylist further up the code if anyone was wondering

```
for(int k =0;k <100; k++){
        Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
        population2.add(new Object[]{solutionList}) ;
        System.out.println("In the loop  " + solutionList);

    }

    for(Object[] row : population2){
        System.out.println("Row = " + Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Each element of `population2` is an array with a reference to the *same* `ArrayList`. If you want different lists, you need to create a new one for each iteration.

For example, to avoid populating the list with the right numbers each time, you could just shuffle `solutionList` and then add a reference to a *copy*:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
    Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(solutionList);
    population2.add(new Object[]{ copy });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
population2.add(new Object[]{solutionList}) ;
```

creates an Object array with a single element. That element happens to be a list.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating 100 arrays, each containing a reference to the same list. I think what you want is creating 100 arrays, each containing a copy of the elements of the list:

```
for(int k =0;k <100; k++){
    Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
    population2.add(solutionList.toArray()) ;
}
```

But I would advise avoiding arrays completely, and always using collections:

```
for(int k =0;k <100; k++){
    Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
    population2.add(new ArrayList<Something>(solutionList));
}
```